# How to swap numbers row with symbols on US keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, numbers

As a programmer I’m typing the symbols on the number row more often on the keyboard than I type the numbers. Using the US keyboard layout, I have to press `shift-7` for example to yield `&`. I’d like to permanently yield `&` without holding `shift` key and only type `7` when I hold the shift key. Effectively swapping numbers with symbols permanently. Is there a way?

Comment: How was your experience with the new setting (layout)? Did you keep it in the last years?

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't change the layout yet to swap numbers with symbols. Also due to having moved to Linux shortly after above question. But your question reminds me to try this finally out. BTW, the French layout has the numbers on shift by default (but their other letters and semicolon, dot, ... layout is too awkward).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom keyboard layout that does this pretty easily with the [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) app.